# How to find DataGridViewRow in DataGridView that is "attached" to DataRow in DataTable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datarow, datagridviewrow

In my example i have got:

```
DataTable dt = SomeMethodThatFillsDataTable();
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView;
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

now I would like to "pick" some DataRows from DataTable and highlight it in DataGridView

```
DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select("someColumn = someTerm");

foreach (DataRow row in foundRows)    
{      
    DataGridViewRow dgvRow = // here i would like to get acces to DataGridViewRow "attached" to row    
    dgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;    
}
```

Any idee how to do this?
Is it possible anyway?

Comment: can you tell me is this datatable is  diffrent from the source od the grid why i am asking that is becuase if this is same than you not need to do the matching . You can use cellformating event and acheive this

Comment: This DataTable is a source of the grid.

Comment: This DataTable is a source of the grid.
I dont want cellformating. Im not sure, but cellformating will format each cell that fulfills terms of formating. 
I want to get to particular DataGridViewRow that is "connected" with my particular DataRow in DataTable.
Lets assume that I would like to make "search" functionality to my application. User clicks button first time - firts row with searched value is highlighted, user clicks button next time - next row is highlighted etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this way

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[someColumn].Value.ToString().Equals(someTerm))
    {
        dgvRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know i can search through all DataGridView rows, however I was hoping that there is a way to do it without looping through all rows.


DataRow dataRow = ((DataRowView)dgv.Rows[x].DataBoundItem).Row;

this way I can find DataGridViewRow in DataTable, maybe there is a way to do it contrariwise.

Comment: You can use dgv_CellFormatting or dgv_DataBindingComplete events instead loop